# LitElement sets template reference to null if the reference is mutated?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, lit-element

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lit-query-iframe?file=Cat.ts) mutates `this.iframe`:

```
  @query("#iframe")
  iframe: any;

  firstUpdated() {
    console.log("THE IFRAME IS: ", this.iframe);
    this.iframe.id = "";
    console.log("THE IFRAME IS: ", this.iframe);
  }
```

After the `this.iframe.id` statement executes `this.iframe` is null.

Any ideas why that's happening?

Answer (score 1):

It's my own bad.  I'm querying the template by id and then changing the id to something else, which then repeats the query and sets the iframe to null since it cannot be found.

Comment: Since there is no real value in question or answer, maybe it is better to remove your question.

Comment: I thought about that too ... But if anyone comes across this dynamic the question might have some value.  I was brand new to lit element when it happened ... it then it dawned on me that I'm a dumb ass :).

Comment: @ole if this remains as informational it might be worth adding to your answer that the selector in `@query` runs again when you call `this.iframe` as that's the gotcha. Then accept your own answer :)